# '.on' click not running function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a function that when it runs new markup is generated on the fly...

```
$('.search input[type="image"]').on('click', function(){

    // Open directions in a map

    if($('#TXT_SAddr').val() === ''){
        return false;
        $('.directions .search').css('background' , '#ff0000'); 
    } else {

        var from = $('#TXT_SAddr').val();
        var to = $('.postal-code').html();
        var directions = 'http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=' + from + '&daddr=' + to + '&output=embed';
        var modal = '<div class="apply-modal modal"><a class="close-apply-now" style="margin-bottom: 20px;"><img src="http://site.co.uk/images/closeModal.png" alt="Close" style="border-width:0px;"></a><div class="holder"><iframe src="'+directions+'" style="border:none; width:100%; height:500px;" border="0"></iframe></div></div>';

        $('body').prepend('<div class="modalOverlay"/>' + modal);

        $('.modal').animate({
                'opacity': 1,
                'top': '100px'
            }, 700, 'easeOutBack');

    }

    return false;

});
```

If you can see, the above generates a div with an anchor under the class name of 'close-apply-now'.

I now want to bind a function to this and I've tried using...

```
$('a.close-apply-now').on('click', function(){
    alert('asdasd');
});
```

with no luck, can anybody see where I may be going wrong? Not even my alert is working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax for event delegation is slightly different.

The event need to be bind to an element which is already existing in the dom while the target element selector needs to be passed as the second argument

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.close-apply-now', function(){
    alert('asdasd');
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Since the `close-apply-now` div is added dynamically, you need to use [`event delegation`](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to register the event handler like:

```
// New way (jQuery 1.7+) - .on(events, selector, handler)
$('body').on('click', 'a.close-apply-now', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('asdasd');
});
```

This will attach your `click` event to any anchors with class **close-apply-now** within the `body` element.

Answer (score 2):

The `close-apply-now` div is added dynamically. You have to add the selector parameter, otherwise the event is directly bound (doesn't work for dynamically loaded content) instead of delegated. See http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events

Change your code to

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.update' ,function(){
```

The jQuery set receives the event then delegates it to elements matching the selector given as argument. This means that contrary to when using `live`, the jQuery set elements must exist when you execute the code.

Use jQuery's live() method. Description: Attach an event handler for all elements which match the current selector, now and in the future.

```
$("a.close-apply-now").live("click", function(){
  alert('asdasd');
});
```

[Try Both in Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yds7T/)